# Upgrade software that worked with Tomcat version 6 to work with version 7

Tags: tomcat7

I have Tomcat 6 on my Ubuntu. Under webapps I have software that was packed as `XXX.war` and it is now running with Tomcat 6. I need to install and to move it to work with Tomcat 7. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

After you installed Tomcat 7 you can place all the *xxx.war* fils in:

```
path\Apache Tomcat - 7.x.xx\webapps
```

It is not actually necessary to restart the server. The hot deployment will take action and you will be able to access your applications.

You can see a complete migration guide [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html).

Comment: But I have already installed my app, i dont want to install it again, i just want tomcat7 to run it not 6

Comment: Well just place the war files in Tomcat7 webapps folder. Stop the Tomcat6 server and start the Tomcat7. You can do this either form your IDE (ie Eclipse) or in command line running shutdown and startup batch files